# Why can't I use arrow operator in initialization list?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, class-members, initialization-list

I'm a beginner in c++. Recently when practicing writing a linked list, I tried to use initialization list for my class constructor to assign NULL to the head->next.

In the class contructor it warned that my arrow operator "expected a '(' or a '{'". Why is there such an error?  (I know I can initialize class members just in the block, but why can't I do this with this pointer?)
Thanks!

Here's my header file for linkedlist:

linkedlist.h

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node {
int val;
node *next;
};

class linkedlist {
private:
node *head;
int listlen;

public:
linkedlist();
void insert(node*, int);
void del(node*);
void reverse(node*);
void traverse(node*);
int random();
~linkedlist();

};
```

And here's my class constructor:

linkedlist.cpp

```
#include "linkedlist.h"
#include <iostream>

linkedlist::linkedlist() :listlen(0), head->next(NULL){}
```

Comment: Two problems: First of all `head` is not initialized. Second, you can't have expressions in the initializer list.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude what about constant expressions?

Comment: Why? Because that's how the language was designed. (Presumably initialization lists have always been intended for initializing the object itself, not other objects that it's members might point to.)

Comment: @JoelCornett It's possible to have non-constant expression as the *initializer*, as the value used to initialize a member variable. But it's not allowed to have general expression for the variable to be initialized (like `head->next`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Oh you know I totally I misread the constructor. I gotcha.

Comment: @Some programmer dude I'm kinda confused about this head pointer. Am I supposed to initialize the head or head->next, or both? Why?

Answer (score 2):

In general you can only initialize the members themselves as part of the initialization lists. If that was your only issue here, then you could just initialize the next-pointer to `NULL` as part of the body of the ctor. However, your member variable `head` is itself a pointer, and not currently pointing anywhere, so I suspect you actually wanted to set `head` itself to `NULL` (or `nullptr` if you're using c++11 or later):

`linkedlist::linkedlist() :listlen(0), head(NULL) {}`

You could also consider additionally adding a ctor to your `struct node` to initialize `next` to `NULL` upon initialization.

A few other things I thought could be worth pointing out since you said you're new:

1. Note that initialization lists aren't run in the order they are written in the ctor, but rather in the order the members are defined in the class' body. In your case here this `listlen` is actually initialized to 0 only after `head` is initialized. This doesn't matter for your code here, but could matter if the initialization of members is more complex and has dependencies. Personally, I'd recommend to always keep the order of the initialization lists matching the order of member definitions. Certain compilers also have flags to warn if that is not the case.
2. Rather than implementing your own linked list, have you considered using a data structure from the standard library? Check out cppreference.com for lots of great information about it. In particular, check out the 'list', 'vector', or 'deque' depending on your use case.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I will have initialization order in mind. And, with regard to data structure itself, are initializing head pointer as NULL and head->next as NULL both necessary?

Comment: Unless you do that, they will have an undefined value, which for pointers means they are invalid and will likely cause you to SEGV should you try to dereference them. For that reason, in most cases, you'd want to initialize them explicitly so you can later on reason about the values. I say "in most cases", because sometimes you might have different state around that let's you guarantee that you won't access these members until they have been initialized.